# Local Ionic Plugin update

Tags: ionic-framework

I have my local ionic plugin.
to install it I do : ionic plugin add myplugin-directory

all goes well, the problem I have is when I want to update the plugin.

I am updating the myplugin-directory , but then I have to remove the plugin and reinstall it.

Is there any better way of doing that ?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, it's kinda time consuming and I hope there is a better way to do this but I haven't found anything yet. Did you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cordova-check-plugins` to update all of the cordova plugins that you have in your Ionic project.
To update my cordova plugins currently I run `cordova-check-plugins --update=auto --target package.json` from the root of my project

If cordova-check-plugins is not installed you can install it using

```
npm install -g cordova-check-plugins
```

[cordova-check-plugins - GitHub](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-check-plugins)

[cordova-check-plugins - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-check-plugins)